# Overlay time series data in Chartkick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, datetime, chartkick

With chartkick can I strip the date so only the time is left so the data can be overlaid on a 24 hour abscissa?

```
<% the_date_time_span = the_date..the_date + 23.hour %>
<% other_date_time_span = other_date..other_date + 23.hour %>

<%= line_chart [
  {name: "One day", data: HourByHour.where(datetime: other_date_time_span).pluck(:datetime, :enphase)},
  {name: "Another day", data: HourByHour.where(datetime: the_date_time_span).pluck(:datetime, :enphase)}      
  ] %>
```

or all in one statement

```
<%= line_chart [
      {name: "One day", data: Hour.where(datetime: other_date_time_span).pluck(:datetime, :enphase)},
      {name: "Another day", data: Hour.where(datetime: the_date_time_span).pluck(:datetime, :enphase)}      
      ]
    %>
```

where

```
 <% the_date_time_span = the_date..the_date + 23.hour %>
 <% other_date_time_span = other_date..other_date + 23.hour %>
```

As expected the abscissa is spread over both days. And they can be months apart.

[image: As expected the abscissa is spread over both days]

`HourByHour.where(datetime: other_date_time_span).pluck(:datetime, :enphase)` results in the following

```
[[Thu, 28 Dec 2023 00:00:00.000000000 PST -08:00, 0.0],
[Thu, 28 Dec 2023 01:00:00.000000000 PST -08:00, 0.0],
[Thu, 28 Dec 2023 02:00:00.000000000 PST -08:00, 0.0],
[Thu, 28 Dec 2023 03:00:00.000000000 PST -08:00, 0.0],
[Thu, 28 Dec 2023 04:00:00.000000000 PST -08:00, 0.0],
[Thu, 28 Dec 2023 05:00:00.000000000 PST -08:00, 0.0],
[Thu, 28 Dec 2023 06:00:00.000000000 PST -08:00, 0.0],
[Thu, 28 Dec 2023 07:00:00.000000000 PST -08:00, 72.0],
[Thu, 28 Dec 2023 08:00:00.000000000 PST -08:00, 520.0],
[Thu, 28 Dec 2023 09:00:00.000000000 PST -08:00, 1346.0],
[Thu, 28 Dec 2023 10:00:00.000000000 PST -08:00, 1802.0],
[Thu, 28 Dec 2023 11:00:00.000000000 PST -08:00, 2688.0],
[Thu, 28 Dec 2023 12:00:00.000000000 PST -08:00, 2771.0],
[Thu, 28 Dec 2023 13:00:00.000000000 PST -08:00, 2379.0],
[Thu, 28 Dec 2023 14:00:00.000000000 PST -08:00, 1320.0],
[Thu, 28 Dec 2023 15:00:00.000000000 PST -08:00, 803.0],
[Thu, 28 Dec 2023 16:00:00.000000000 PST -08:00, 109.0],
[Thu, 28 Dec 2023 17:00:00.000000000 PST -08:00, 0.0],
[Thu, 28 Dec 2023 18:00:00.000000000 PST -08:00, 0.0],
[Thu, 28 Dec 2023 19:00:00.000000000 PST -08:00, 0.0],
[Thu, 28 Dec 2023 20:00:00.000000000 PST -08:00, 0.0],
[Thu, 28 Dec 2023 21:00:00.000000000 PST -08:00, 0.0],
[Thu, 28 Dec 2023 22:00:00.000000000 PST -08:00, 0.0],
[Thu, 28 Dec 2023 23:00:00.000000000 PST -08:00, 0.0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Ruby has `Date` and `DateTime` but doesn't offer actual `Time` (of day, without date part). To add one, you could consider [Time-of-Day gem](https://github.com/JackC/tod).

A workaround would be unifying the date across your timestamps so that they all end up overlaying on it, leaving only varying time of day. [DB<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/7E8liQm4)

```ruby
.pluck('now()::date+datetime::time')
```

This would extract the time part from each of your values, placing it on the current date.

Comment: I can't see how this would work. I edited the OP to perhaps better show the logic. But the date needs to be available to get the data from the database. The transformation to time without date has to occur after the coordinates are extracted from the database.

Comment: You still keep the `.where()` to target which records you want and you of course still need to also `.pluck()` the actual `enphase` values. This is just meant to show how to change the date part of the incoming timestamps on the fly. It doesn't influence which records will be taken, and the expression doesn't remove the date; it takes the value of `now()`, takes the date from that, then to that it adds the time part of your field called `datetime`. So you're effectively getting a full timestamp with the date and time, but all date parts are moved to today, so that your reds and blues overlay.

Comment: Thanks I guess I wasn't understanding the value of datetime when pluck acted on it. And I can't or haven't understood what exactly what pluck is doing. I may look at it again. I did work out a loop to strip the date using TOD from each datetime and create a new array. Answer can't be posted here. Got some AI help although anyone who knew the timedate actions would be able to figure it out. Challenge is casting the class and dealing with quote when the data becomes a string. Thank you